# Given $\frac{f(a)}{a}=\frac{f(b)}{b}$ prove there exist $c\in (a,b)$ so that: $cf'(c)=f(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)$ is continous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$ where $0<a<b$. Given $\frac{f(a)}{a}=\frac{f(b)}{b}$ prove there exist $c\in (a,b)$ so that:

$cf'(c)=f(c)$

I know I probably need to define some function and use Rolle's theorem but I can't figure out how to find that function...

Comment: $bf(a)=af(b)$ Define $xg(x)=f(x)$

Comment: Then $\log(x)+\log(g(x))=\log(f(x))$  $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Comment: What happens at a point $c\in\mathopen]a,b[$ where $\displaystyle x\longmapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ attains its maximum or minimum? (And *why* does such a point exists?).

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$. Show that Rolle's theorem can be applied for $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$. This will give you the required $c$.